# Java Bukkit: setFlySpeed()

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I'm making my own plugin in Java Bukkit... and i found a problem that i can't solve it...

I'm setting the Player's Argument... then i have to set the 2nd Argument (the FlySpeed) an then im Converting it from String to Double.
Now i'm Coverting again the Double to Float... :\

**For a reason... it don't Converts right the Double to Float.**

```java
Player playerToSetFlySpeed = Bukkit.getPlayer(args[0]);
String speed = args[1];
double speedDouble = Double.parseDouble(Speed);
float speedFloat = (float) SpeedDouble;
playerToSetFlySpeed.setFlySpeed(SpeedFloat);
```

**The Error in Minecraft Sayes: An Error occurred while attampting to perform this command**
**and the Command Looks like: /setspeed (player) (amount_of_speed)** im writing the amount of speed as a String and it (has to) convert it to Double and Then to Float.

I'm Working on [IntelliJ IDEA 13.1](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)

please Help me.. that's very important for my Plugin... :\

Comment: "IT DON'T WORKS !!!" is not a problem description. (Explain error messages or why the outcome isn't as expected, etc.)

Comment: So, how did you solve the issue? Please share your answer with us.

Comment: i didn't solve it..yet.. but i tried a lot if things.. Like:
 


`float SpeedFloat = Float.parseFloat(SpeedDouble);`

Comment: What *does* it convert to then, and why is it not "right"? How does this relate to the value of args[1]? (And no, the IDE doesn't matter.)

Comment: Please name your local fields in `camelCase`, not `PascalCase`. It helps with the syntax coloring.

Comment: Can you refer to the error in your server console and give relevant section of the log?

Comment: Thats the Log: http://pastebin.com/S0avy8za

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [`org.bukkit.entity.Player#setFlySpeed(float)` documents this behaviour:](http://gyazo.com/00184d11b1e8529d80c8df2c2e622881.png)
>
> Sets the speed at which a client will fly. Negative values indicate reverse directions.
>
> Parameters:
>
> - **value** The new speed, from -1 to 1.
>
> Throws:
>
> - [IllegalArgumentException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) If new speed is less than -1 or greater than 1

As seen from your log:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 10.0 is too high
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_7_R1.entity.CraftPlayer.validateSpeed(CraftPlayer.java:1158) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-2-g85f5776-b3024jnks]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_7_R1.entity.CraftPlayer.setFlySpeed(CraftPlayer.java:1129) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-2-g85f5776-b3024jnks]
    at me.jimisdam.BukkitPlugins.Helper.Helper.onCommand(Helper.java:171) ~[?:?]
    at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:44) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-2-g85f5776-b3024jnks]
    ... 13 more
```

You've used an invalid argument: 10.

You need to make sure the argument is valid before calling `setFlySpeed()`:

```
{
    // ...
    float speed = (float) SpeedDouble;
    if(speed > 1 || speed < -1) {
        commandSender.sendMessage("You have specified an argument out of range!");
        return;
    }
    playerToSetFlySpeed.setFlySpeed(speed);
}
```

Comment: This caveat in your code was kind of obvious by looking at the stack trace and javadocs... Please learn to debug your code yourself next time.

Comment: Owww.. Thanx so if i want to have from 0 to 10 i have to set it...

0.1 = 1
1.0 = 10
so i have to multiple it by 10.. Thank you so much ... :) :D

Comment: No, it's dividing by 10. You should read up how Essentials manipulates with commands, that way you wouldn't make mistakes. https://github.com/essentials/Essentials

Comment: ow.. ok..right.. i just tried what i sayed and ... your Right !!! :D
Anyway... thnx 4 all :DD